# How to Go To previous Url with an Error from Observer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am working on Magento 2 Extension i am trying to implement an event `customer_save_before`

What i want to do is.. if user email is from a domain like abc.com it should go to Previous URL with an error abc.com is Not Allowed

Comment: do you get your answer or still looking for this one?

Comment: The Answer by @Marius is Working Great Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`customer_save_before` is an event linked to the customer model. So it's not a good idea to redirect from the observer on that event since you won't know exactly where is triggered.
You should just throw an instance of `\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException` in case your criteria does not match.
For example

```
public function execute(....)
{
    if (domain is not allowed) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__("DOmain is not allowed"));
    }
}
```

and exception handling and redirection should be handled by the controllers that call your observer, or different observers that are dispatched in controller context.
For the frontend account creation this should already be handled.
in `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost::execute()`, the line that creates the customer account

```
$customer = $this->accountManagement
            ->createAccount($customer, $password, $redirectUrl);
```

is already in a `try-catch` block.
on the `catch (LocalizedException $e)` section, the exception message is just added to the message list and after it the user gets redirected back to the account create page.
In theory you should only need to throw the exception I mentioned above.
You can also check how it works on the admin part, but I think it works in a similar way.